# Realm object vs collection notifications

Tags: swift, realm

**Question**: Does adding an observer to an object trigger notifications when an object in that object's List property changes? It doesn't appear to.

However, if an observer is added to an object in a collection (via a filter), it does trigger a notification if an object in that objects List property changes.

**Why am I asking**: In this use case, I know the specific person I want to observe and need to know about changes in that persons (and no others) Dogs - specifically if the dogs location changes

**Code**:

```
class PersonClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var person_id = NSUUID().uuidString
    let dogs = List<DogClass>()
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "person_id"
    }
}

class DogClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var dog_id = NSUUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var location = ""
    let person = LinkingObjects(fromType: PersonClass.self, property: "dogs")
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "dog_id"
    }
}
```

In this first case, we add an observer to a specific person (token is defined as a class var of NotificationToken?)

```
let person = realm.object(ofType: PersonClass.self,
                                  forPrimaryKey: self.personId)
self.token = person.observe { change in
   print("person object change notification")
}
```

then if we modify a dogs location, we do not receive a notification.

in this second case the person (results collection) is retrieved via a filter and then add an observer through a CollectionChange notification

```
let personResults = realm.objects(PersonClass.self)
                         .filter("person_id == %@", self.personId)
self.token = personResults.observe { (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
    print("collection change notification)
}
```

Then, if a dogs location is changed, we do receive a notification.

**Additional Info**: My implementation could be incorrect so is there a way to observe an object (person.observe) where changes to it's dogs List also generate a notification?

Is using the collection observer the only option?

Comment: "In this first case, we add an observer to a specific person (token is defined as a class var of NotificationToken?)"  They never say where they use their code.  "if we modify a dogs location, we do not receive a notification."  That'll be a tough sell since you don't show how you modify your data.

Comment: @ElTomato Not sure I understand the comment. If we add an observer to a person and and some point the Dog object has their location set i.e. rex.location = "Back yard" that would trigger a notification (in the second example at least). Do you need to see the realm.write { dog.location = "Back yard" } code?